# Ни как не получается дописать регулярку

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть текст:

> [asdasd|asda sdas] asdasd fneughwegh [4ghehrh|gfebgubegoe] sdfsdfsf

Мне нужно получить из него:

```
[asdasd|asda sdas]
[4ghehrh|gfebgubegoe]
```

Я написал вот такую регулярку: `\[.*\|.*\]`

Она возвращает вот это: `[asdasd|asda sdas] asdasd fneughwegh [4ghehrh|gfebgubegoe]`

Т.е. берет первую скобку, и последнюю. Почему?

Comment: пробелы могут быть в квадратных скобках? какие вообще там могут быть символы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

без подробностей пока так:

```js
var str = '[asdasd|asdasdas] asdasd fneughwegh [4ghehrh|gfebgubegoe] sdfsdfsf';
var re = /(\[[^\s]+\|[^\s]+\])/gi;
var found = str.match(re);

console.log(found);
```

то есть предполагаю, что внутри скобок нет пробелов, а остальные символы разрешены

---

если пробелы нужны:

```js
var str = '[asd asd|asda sdas] asdasd fneughwegh [4ghehrh|gfebgubegoe] sdfsdfsf';
var re = /(\[.*?\|.*?\])/gi;
var found = str.match(re);

console.log(found);
```

Проблема описана в википедии:

> В некоторых реализациях квантификаторам в регулярных выражениях
>   соответствует максимально длинная строка из возможных (квантификаторы
>   являются жадными, англ. greedy). Это может оказаться значительной
>   проблемой. Например, часто ожидают, что выражение (<.*>) найдёт в
>   тексте теги HTML. Однако если в тексте есть более одного HTML-тега, то
>   этому выражению соответствует целиком строка, содержащая множество
>   тегов.
>
> `<p><b>Википедия</b> — свободная энциклопедия, в которой <i>каждый</i> может изменить или дополнить любую статью.</p>`
>
> Эту проблему можно решить двумя способами.
>
> 1. Учитывать символы, не соответствующие желаемому образцу (<[^>]*> для
>      вышеописанного случая).
> 2. Определить квантификатор как *нежадный
>      (ленивый, англ. lazy)* — большинство реализаций позволяют это сделать,
>      добавив после него знак вопроса.

```
Жадный | Ленивый
  *    |   *?
  +    |   +?
 {n,}  |  {n,}?
```

Comment: К сожалению, пробелы таки могут быть.

Comment: @ИльяБизунов значит надо огласить список всех разрешенных и неразрешенных символов внутри... причем как до, так и после знака `|`

Comment: @ИльяБизунов добавил вариант с где учитываются и пробелы тоже  и написал почему так))